# Refreshing UAT with production content + HNSC sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, content-database, content-migration, hnsc

We have Hosted Names Site Collections in both **UAT** and **Production** and I am in the process of Refreshing the **UAT** db with prod db, I have these

1. Take a backup of the prod db
2. Detach the DB of QA from the QA WebApp
3. Mount the Dev db on the QA WebApp

since the Sites are Host Based Site Collection and I have over 400 sites on 1 db - I assumed since I am mounting the db on uat webapp http://uat-webappname it would refresh all the sc url to http://uat-sitename but it is not i.e., url is still http:sitename
`Set-SPSite -Identity -Url` on each site is not feasible to set the url, do I have anyother alternative to do this? as I have 8+ content db with each holding 200+ **Site Collections.**